# Enable mobile device users to toggle div between `position: fixed` and `position: static` (or 'relative')

Tags: css, mobile, css-position, mobile-devices

I am just getting back into web design and a ton has changed.  I'm going through lots of css tutorials at the moment, and I just read about position: fixed and its [problems with mobile browsers](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/).

That is reason enough for me to ignore it and move on to more important things, but I got wondering... what if I had a little "pin" icon that the user could toggle to "un-fix" that element if they found it troublesome for them?  Possible?

By "un-fix", yes I mean change it from fixed back to static/default.

And no, not a simple viewport logic setup where mobile can't see it... because "mobile" isn't simply defined.  It is only a problem on SOME browsers, so I think it should be left up to the user, mobile or otherwise.  Click the pin, it is no longer... well... pinned.  That way the aberrant behaviour of certain browsers can be mitigated by the user.

Comment: So you're saying a mobile user would tap a "pin" icon and the element with `position: fixed` would be released to something else? What would that something else be? Maybe you should provide a few more specifics in your question.

Comment: If changing an element to `position:static` is unproblematic, layout-wise, I would suggest leaving it set to `position:static` altogether and not jump through hoops with new UI elements to toggle it. By the way, looking at the page that describes the problems, it's not all that bad: most browsers either ignore fixed, or let the element scroll but then pop it back into the fixed position after scrolling. I could live with that.

Comment: @MrLister, completely agree. The video and article referenced in the question describe a user experience issue that's really not so bad. If it were serious, the reviewer wouldn't have been able to test all those devices and platforms, because Google, Samsung, Apple etc wouldn't have implemented `position: fixed` in the first place.

Comment: @bcsteeve, Yes I left a comment. No, I didn't downvote your question.

Comment: @bcsteeve, consider that maybe there are people on SO who request clarification and more details before they even consider a downvote, while others may just scan a question, notice deficiencies, downvote and move on.

Comment: @Michael_B yes, of course... sorry.

Comment: Regarding whether or not it is a bad user experience... I think, like the guy in the video says, it is horrible.  If the jumping "fixed" bar is going to happen, then I think it is better to never use it because that is pretty bad.  But giving the user a choice to discard the effect puts them in control.  If the implied answers here are, "I don't know" or "can't be done" then that's fine and I'd probably choose not utilizing fixed on mobiles or at all, although that seems heavy-handed.  "they wouldn't have implemented in the first place" assumes that they are perfect.  They're not.

Comment: @MrLister leaving it as static doesn't answer the question.  Of course it is "unproblematic".  Fancy UI should always be an "if supported". The problem here is that the fixed position is semi-supported.  Simply not using it removes my flexibility as a designer.  Simply using it removes the ability of some users to enjoy a good user experience.  If there is a way to "unfix" by the user, then there's a happy medium.

Comment: No problem. Apology accepted (and unnecessary). Yes, I can see that a quality debate can be held on this issue. I'm not saying mobile implementation of `position: fixed` is perfect. Just that Google, Apple, Amazon etc have found it good enough to implement.

Comment: If you're still interested in an answer to this question, let me know. I have some ideas.

Comment: I'm researching this now out of personal interest. If I find a good solution that answers your question or may help others I'll post it. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give users the control to **manually** release a fixed element, here's one simple concept for a solution:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u2vnsb49/)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="fixed">
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p id="release-button"><a href="#">click here to release</a></p>
    <br>
    <p><i>Just an illustration of a concept.
          Not built to toggle. Click 'Run' to refresh.</i></p>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
     body { height: 1500px; }

    #fixed {
        width: 95%;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: #ff0;
        border: 1px solid #ccc;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        position: fixed;

    }

    .static {position: static !important;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#release-button').click(function() {
    $('#fixed').addClass('static');
});
```

---

To provide for an **automatic** release of a fixed element on a mobile device use media queries:

Example:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
}

@media only screen and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    footer {
        position: static; /* or relative */
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm talking about!  I'm learning pretty quick that JQuery has the answer to just about everything I have a question for.  I don't think the "automatic release" is suitable [in my mind] just because then you're forcing 100-X% of mobile users to not have the designed experience for the sake of the X%

Comment: @bcsteeve, in thinking about your question and reading more about `position: fixed` on mobile devices, I've come to agree with you. It's a user experience issue that needs improvement. Although we disagree on severity (I don't think it's a big deal), that's besides the point. Considering that current functionality could be irritating to some mobile users, all users should be afforded the option to unpin a fixed element. A simple 'x' they can tap to unpin it would suffice. You raised a good point +1.

Comment: On a different note, it's possible you were originally downvoted for the way in which you phrased your question. The title was somewhat vague and broad. I edited earlier today for clarity, search and a narrower  scope. For future reference, here are some tips you may find useful: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: And lastly, I included the "automatic" option just fyi, and for others who may find this answer via search but hadn't considered this possibility.