# Why is my nav bar with 'position:fixed' displaying at bottom of web page not bottom of viewport on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, webview

I have a navigation bar which has its position set to fixed. This works fine as expected on browesrs and on mobile browsers as expected. The navigation bar is positioned at the botton of the viewport and everything else scrolls under it.

But then same page when moved to a mobile web view in an app, it  render the navigation bar at the very end of the page so that I have to scroll down to see it.

I comes on the device view only when I change the top position to around 50%.

It also seems that if I remove everything from that page with only empty ,  I still see vertical scroll bar even though my page is empty.

Comment: Can you please [edit] your question to include your code (or actually, preferably a [mcve])?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `position: fixed` on mobile devices has several known issues. Among them is the behavior of the fixed element, which doesn't always stay fixed.

Although your problem may be in your code, that may not be the problem since you mention that your nav bar is working well across various mobile browsers.

Here's a review of `position: fixed` tested across multiple mobile platforms and devices:

**[Fixed Positioning in Mobile Browsers](http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/)**

Here's an answer I provided to a related question a few days ago:

**[Enable mobile device users to toggle div between `position: fixed` and `position: static` (or 'relative')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666269/enable-mobile-device-users-to-toggle-div-between-position-fixed-and-position/31684528)**

Hope this helps. Good luck!

Comment: I think the issue for me is not exactly the position:fixed. It seems the device somehow calculate the page height = viewport height and put the footer at the bottom of the page rather than the bottom of the viewport. I have to set bottom:50% to bring it to the edge of the screen.

Comment: Okay. But since you're using `position: fixed` on mobile devices, you should still take a look at the video and article referenced in my answer. It may help you with troubleshooting now, or in the future.

Comment: Also, if you haven't already, take a look at this property: `vh` (viewport height). If you google "CSS viewport units" you'll find another way to place and size things relative to the viewport.

Comment: Thanks, even vh is also placing the nav bar at the bottom.

Comment: Well, `vh` is relatively new. It may not be supported by your browser / app. http://caniuse.com/#search=vh

Comment: Did you get it to work? Is the problem with one browser / device or multiple?

Comment: not yet. there is no issue at all on desktop browser, mobile browser. the problem is only when the whole thing got integrated into a mobile webview app on android.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84913/discussion-between-suraj-and-michael-b).